# Mail Body Duplicating when using Foreach Loop in Php

Tags: php, email, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to send emails to multiple users with the same email body but with different string variables. My code is as below :

```
$sql = "Select Trainee_Name,Session_ID FROM Session_Trainee WHERE Session_id='".$statement."'";
$fetched=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) ; 
if( $fetched === false ) { die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));}
while($sno=sqlsrv_fetch_array($fetched,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $Trainee_Name[]=$sno['Trainee_Name'];
    $Session_ID=$sno['Session_ID'];
}
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                
    $mail->Host       = "xxxxx"; 
    $mail->SetFrom('xxxxx');
    $mail->Subject    = "xxxxx"";
foreach($Trainee_Name as $traineename)
{   
//$email_body = $email_body ."Dear ". $Trainee_Name .",<br/><br/>";
    $email_body = $email_body ."A <strong>  Session Evaluation Form</strong> form has been sent for Evaluation to you  <br/>";  
    $email_body = $email_body ."<Strong><p><a href='http://xxxxx/Evaluation/form3.php?Session_id=$statement';> Click here to proceed with the evaluation </a>Immediate Evaluation Form</p></strong>";
    $email_body = $email_body ."<Strong><p><a href='http://xxxxx/Evaluation/pre_evaluation.php?Session_id=$statement';> Click here to proceed with the evaluation </a>Pre Evaluation Form</p></strong>";
    $email_body = $email_body ."<Strong><p><a href='http://xxxxx/Evaluation/post_evaluation.php?Session_id=$statement';> Click here to proceed with the evaluation </a>Post Evaluation Form</p></strong>";
    $mail->MsgHTML($email_body);
    $username="xxxxx";
    $password="xxxxx";
    $lc = ldap_connect("xxxxx") or
    die("Couldn't conn/ect to AD!");
    ldap_set_option($lc, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_bind($lc,$username,$password);
    $base = "OU=xxxxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxxxx";
    $filt = "(&(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(name=$traineename*))))";
    $sr = @ldap_search($lc, $base, $filt);
    $info = ldap_get_entries($lc, $sr);
    for ($j = 0; $j < $info["count"]; $j++) 
    {
        $add = $info[$j]['mail'][0];
        $address[] = $add;
        echo $add."<br/>";
        ///$mail->AddAddress($add); 
        $mail->AddAddress('xxxxx'); 
    }
    if ($j == 0)
    {
        echo "No matches found!<br/>";
    }
        ldap_close($lc);
    }
    if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row["email"]) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br />';
        } else {
            echo "Session Details Sent to the Trainees";
        }
}
```

The mails are being sent to the users, but the body is duplicated in each mail. I.e. if there are 3 trainee names, the body is duplicated thrice in each mail. Below is a screenshot of a mail :

[image]

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Is the syntax error present here in your actual code? You have an extra double quote on the line that is like this: `$mail->Subject    = "xxxxx"";` <-- You have two closing quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You have to initiate the `email_body` variable on each loop:

```
foreach($Trainee_Name as $traineename)
{   
//$email_body = $email_body ."Dear ". $Trainee_Name .",<br/><br/>";
    $email_body = "A <strong>  Session Evaluation Form</strong> form has been sent for Evaluation to you  <br/>";  
 //rest of the loop code...
}
```

In your current code, you're concatenating this variable in each loop, without starting from an empty one.

Comment: Have done the changes but still getting the duplicates.

Comment: Strange, it shouldn't... Does the first line "Dear...." of your loop is indeed commented in your actual code?

Comment: Tested the correction online, looks good to me: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/49790a5cd6fe7cbe3012568fe9876b3dfc2ef681   In comparison, your initial code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8639d633fa0eefa31381e277ea919d3489b38dcd

Comment: @NjiruMwaniki Since there is no other place with `email_body` here, you might have another problem elsewhere than this code portion.